# Any good way to fix this particulat tri problem?

Tags: mesh

I have a tri problem with my mesh and I wanna find out if it can be fixed in any way

[image]

[image]

EDIT: file---> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you don't want any more triangle?

- Select your edge
- Subdivide it with <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide
- Join the 2 vertices with <kbd>J</kbd>
- Dissolve the edge with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*
- Move the new vertice along its edge with <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm somewhat new to the blender and I need to learn the problem-solving methods. Thanks again!